# How to eager load association for an array of model records

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

I have an array of Rails model records. Is it possible to eager load an association for all these records in one go (query)?

Sometimes I only have an array instead of an AR::Scope. And sometimes I want to dynamically choose what to eager load later.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

In Rails 3, one can use [preloader](http://rubydoc.info/docs/rails/3.2.8/ActiveRecord/Associations/Preloader) to eager-load associations on existing records.

```
ActiveRecord::Associations::Preloader.new(posts,:comments).run()
```

In Rails 4.1+ the call signature [changed slightly](http://apidock.com/rails/v4.2.1/ActiveRecord/Associations/Preloader):

```
ActiveRecord::Associations::Preloader.new.preload(posts,:comments)
```

Comment: This is deprecated in Rails 4.2

Comment: Rails4: `ActiveRecord::Associations::Preloader.new.preload(posts, :catalogs)`

Comment: @LeoCorrea I don't see it's deprecated in Rails 4.2. Can you give some hint where I can find the deprecation note? Thanks.

Comment: `ActiveRecord::Associations::Preloader.new.preload(posts,:comments)` still works in Rails 5!

Answer (score 2):

Well, you could refind those objects. Map ':id' over your array, to get the records' ids, and then refind, this time eager-loading.

If your array of, say, `Post` model records is `posts`, then it'd be:

```
Post.find(posts.map &:id).includes(:blah)
```

Comment: My set is quite large so this reloading is too expensive. I was hoping for an API way.